# Interbase SQL remake a Select query

Tags: sql, select, sum, case, interbase

I need you help.

I have an Interbase SQL Select query:

> Select aps.fullname, aps.productvcode, aps.alccode, aps.capacity, Cast(Round(Sum(case when wp.capacity>0 then wp.quantity * wp.capacity/10
>   else wp.quantity * wp.capacity end),4) as DECIMAL(18,4)) as WBTotal from
>   AP aps left join Waybill_positions wp on wp.alccode=aps.alccode where
>   wp.alccode='0001821000001389010' group by aps.fullname,
>   aps.productvcode, aps.alccode, aps.capacity
>   union all
>   Select aps.fullname, aps.productvcode, aps.alccode, aps.capacity,
>   Cast(Round(Sum(case when wp.capacity>0 then wp.quantity * wp.capacity/10
>   else wp.quantity * wp.capacity end),4) as DECIMAL(18,4)) as WBTotal from
>   AP aps left join Waybill_out_positions wp on wp.alccode=aps.alccode
>   where wp.alccode='0001821000001389010' group by aps.fullname,
>   aps.productvcode, aps.alccode, aps.capacity

And it gives me this: [image]

But I want the value *"156,9750"* from the second row to be a separate column on the right beside **"WBTOTAL"** and have the title **"WBOTOTAL"**

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CTE, like below

```
with CTE1 as
(
    Select aps.fullname, aps.productvcode, aps.alccode, aps.capacity, Cast(Round(Sum(case when wp.capacity>0 then wp.quantity * wp.capacity/10 else wp.quantity * wp.capacity end),4) as DECIMAL(18,4)) as WBTotal from AP aps left join Waybill_positions wp on wp.alccode=aps.alccode where wp.alccode='0001821000001389010' group by aps.fullname, aps.productvcode, aps.alccode, aps.capacity
),
CTE2 as
(
    Select aps.fullname, aps.productvcode, aps.alccode, aps.capacity, Cast(Round(Sum(case when wp.capacity>0 then wp.quantity * wp.capacity/10 else wp.quantity * wp.capacity end),4) as DECIMAL(18,4)) as WBTotal from AP aps left join Waybill_out_positions wp on wp.alccode=aps.alccode where wp.alccode='0001821000001389010' group by aps.fullname, aps.productvcode, aps.alccode, aps.capacity
)
Select CTE1.fullname, CTE1.productvcode, CTE1.alccode, CTE1.capacity, CTE1.WBTotal, CTE2.WBTotal as WBOTOTAL
From  CTE1 
join  CTE2
on CTE1.productvcode = CTE2.productvcode
and CTE1.alccode = CTE2.alccode
```

Comment: Worked... Thanks.. Can I add other tables just the same way?

Comment: @SovereignSun, sure you can have multiple CTE in one query. You can have more reference in this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

Comment: One more questions.. If I haven't a record in the CTE2 i want it to show 0,000 how?

Comment: @SovereignSun, use left join instead of join. Coalesce(CTE2.WBTotal, 0) as WBOTOTAL

Comment: it did the job... if I need to sum WBTOTAL and WBOTOTAL is it: SUM(Coalesce(CTE2.WBOTOTAL, 0)+Coalesce(CTE1.WBTOTAL, 0)) as TOTAL?

Comment: You don't need SUM, just Coalesce(CTE2.WBOTOTAL,0)+Coalesce(CTE1.WBTOTAL, 0) as TOTAL should work.